# $\#P$ closure under binomial coefficients?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

It is quite straightforward to understand $\#P$ closure under addition and multiplication since there are canonical $NTM$ constructions.

Is there illustrative non-trivial example to understand $NTM$ construction for closure under binomial coefficients?

Comment: Can you specify in your question what does it mean for $\#P$ to be closed under binomial coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a guess: you mean an operation of the form $f(x) \mapsto \binom{f(x)}{d}$, where $d$ is a constant. Let's assume also that $f(x)$ is the number of $y$ such that $\phi(x,y)$. Then $\binom{f(x)}{d}$ is the number of $d$-tuples $y_1,\ldots,y_d$ such that $y_1 < \cdots < y_d$ and $\phi(x,y_1) \land \cdots \land \phi(x,y_d)$.

Comment: Nice. I just saw in "intro to complexity and cryptology" that they actually mean $\binom{f}{g}$, where $g\in\# P$ is bounded by a polynomial (not sure about what happens if $g>f$).

Comment: This could result in exponential blowup, so there is no closure for trivial reasons.

Comment: If $g$ is polynomially bounded then $\binom{f}{g}\le 2^{poly(n)}$.

Comment: So we might have closure when $g$ is polynomially bounded, but not in general. A polytime machine can have an exponential number of accepting paths.

Comment: Yes. The book doesn't claim anything for general $g\in\#P$, the proof doesn't seem very straightforward so I'm currently too lazy to read it.

Comment: It's easy to do $\binom{f+g}{g} = \sum_{d \leq g} \binom{f}{d} \binom{g}{d}$.

Comment: How do you compute $g$? If $g$ was in FP then this would have worked.

Comment: I don't compute $g$. I go over all ordered $d$-tuples of witnesses for $g$ (using some a priori polynomial upper bound on $g$), and for each of them I go over all ordered $d$-tuples of witnesses for $f$.

Comment: My mistake, this seems to work! hhmmm are you suggesting to compute $\binom{(f-g)+g}{g}$, because this would require closure under subtraction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70984/discussion-between-ariel-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: Yes, that's not a complete solution. Some additional ideas are needed.

Comment: @Ariel any updates on this?